# Error in Random Forest implementation using R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am still a beginner in ML algorithms.
I was trying to apply Random Forest on a dataset but I faced an error while trying to fit the model.
Below is the error

```
rf <- randomForest(winequality.red$quality ~ ., data=train)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = winequality.red$quality ~ .,
> data = train,  :    variable lengths differ (found for
> 'fixed.acidity')

I can send the data set and code if needed.
thanks in advance for any hints.
Best
Mohammed

Comment: don't use `$` in a formula, `randomForest(quality ~ ., data=train)` should work

Comment: @rawr probably means randomForest(quality ~ ., data=winequality.red)

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i got a warning while trying this

Comment: rf <- randomForest(quality ~ . , data=train)
Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
>

Comment: that worked:rf <- randomForest(as.factor(quality) ~ . , data=train)
> rf

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.factor(quality) ~ ., data = train) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 0.98%
Confusion matrix:
     0 1 class.error
0 1107 0   0.0000000
1   11 2   0.8461538
>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the formula [interface](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula).

With `data` you specify which dataset you are using.
Then you give a `formula` where you can specify, which variables are the independent/dependent or however you call these.

Your formuala probably should be

```
rf <- randomForest(quality ~ ., data=winequality.red)
```

This would mean, you are using the dataset `winequality.red`.
From this dataset, you want to build a model that predicts `quality`.
The variable before the `~` (tilde) is always, what you want to predict (dependent variable). The `.` after the tilde basically says, you want to use all other variables of your dataset to build a model for the prediction. So after the `~`you specify the independent variables. Names for dependent/independent can vary quite a bit... based on the context (e.g. predicted / predictor, ...)

This is a classical example:

```
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
```

You have the iris dataset, a dataset with measurements of flowers.

```
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num  
 $ Petal.Length: num  
 $ Petal.Width : num  
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor"
```

You want to build a model, to predict, in which category / to which Species a flower belongs. In the above code you say `data=iris` to give the while dataset to the function. Then you specify with the `formula` what the model should look like. In this case we want to predict the Species, so we put `Species` before the `~` with the `.` after the tilde we say, that `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width` shall be used to predict the `Species`.

But we do not refer to them as `iris$Species` in the `formula`, since the function already know, at which dataset it should look at for the variables.